# How to add gradient color to an Image Button in Android Studio with maximum color at center

Tags: android, user-interface, gradient, selector, android-resources

I am new to Android. I am working on the UI Designs of an app. I couldn't achieve the result by following the layer-list. I have to apply gradient coloring to a Image button.[gradient color button I have to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTIJu.png)

My Resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#1d976c"
        android:endColor="#1d976c"
        android:centerColor="#001510"
        android:gradientRadius="5dp"
        android:centerX="20%"/>
    <size
        android:height="100dp"
        android:width="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

[Gradient background which I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsWOQ.png)
How can I get center black colour & top and bottom of same length coloring.?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use layer list to get the result.
Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp" android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"/>
            <gradient
               android:angle="270"
               android:centerColor="#001510"
               android:centerX="60%"
               android:endColor="#1d976c"
               android:gradientRadius="5dp"
               android:startColor="#001510" />
           <size
               android:width="50dp"
               android:height="100dp" />
       </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners  android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
            <gradient
               android:angle="270"
               android:centerColor="#001510"
               android:centerX="50%"
               android:endColor="#001510"
               android:gradientRadius="5dp"
               android:startColor="#1d976c" />
          <size
              android:width="50dp"
              android:height="100dp" />
       </shape>
    </item>
 </layer-list>
```

Play with `android:centerX` to get your result

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. play with the colors on how you want it. change the colors to make it match https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTIJu.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:gradientRadius="50%"
    android:startColor="#00C4DD"
    android:centerColor="#00303C"
    android:endColor="#00C4DD" />
<corners android:radius="30dp" />

</shape>
```